# Include Google Apps Services in chrome developer console (eg CalendarApp)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-chrome-devtools

Working on a container-bound script that uses the [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/), and it would be super helpful to try things out in chrome's console. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you can just use "google oauth2 playground"
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to try any google api live.